# Solr Cloud - Solr Hanging / can't start OR Could not fully create collection: <collection_name>

Tags: solr, solrcloud

My creation/deletion of Solr collections doesn't work anymore.
When I launch a creation (via a curl), I have the following answer (after 30sec):

`Error 500 - Could not fully create collection: <collection_name>`

EDIT: I had another time, the same issue: Solr couldn't fully reboot, or was hanging.

HDP: 2.6.2
Solr(Cloud): 5.5.5
ZK: 3.4.6

Comment: Is this SolrCloud? I ask because you are using ZooKeeper and SolrCloud is a very different beast from Solr.

Comment: Hey kellyfj, yes indeed its solrCloud, I have updated the description. Actually, I had resolved this (and added the answer too)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have struggled so many days with that problem !

In fact, the overseer queue was too large in Zookeeper:

`zkCli.sh -server zkhost:2181 ls /solr/overseer/queue`
and 
`zkCli.sh -server zkhost:2181 ls /solr/overseer/queue-work`
returned several 100k  entries and kept growing !

Process to recover:
1. Stop Solr Nodes
2. Remove overseer queues and recreate them:
`zkCli.sh -server zkhost:2181 rmr /solr/overseer/queue`
`zkCli.sh -server zkhost:2181 create  /solr/overseer/queue`
`zkCli.sh -server zkhost:2181 rmr /solr/overseer/queue-work null`
`zkCli.sh -server zkhost:2181 create  /solr/overseer/queue-work null`
3. Start solr Nodes

We can see in the code:
https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/dbed8bafe6ee167361599deaa4f1b5fdbb0b1c32/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/cloud/api/collections/CreateCollectionCmd.java#L170
The Code try to create the nodes for the Solr collection, then during 30sec poll Zookeeper to check if it has created the nodes. If not it fails with "Could not fully create collection:"

Comment: We've got a similar issue when asking Solr to reload a collection.
`null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: reload the collection time out:180s
at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.sendToOCPQueue`

In our case the `/overseer/collection-queue-work/` was containing a large number of items. Clearing it seems to solve the issue.